# sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to examine my chrome history file using python. Here's my code:

```
import sqlite3

history = sqlite3.connect('/Users/**my_name**/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History')

cur = history.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tasks")
rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

I get the error

> sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

when I try to run the script. Other answers say that the problem is within the SQL file itself, but I'm not the creator of the google history file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is Google Chrome open while you're trying to do this? Sometimes you can't write to a file that another process is already using, and it will say it's locked.

Comment: Yes actually. I'm not trying to write to the file though, only make rows based on what I've read. Did I do something wrong?